Parts of the Edit Page
I don't know Drupal, but I need to be able to talk about Drupal with someone and I don't know what to call things, and I can't figure this one out from the rest of the Internet.
I have a Drupal 10 website.  A page in the site has a row of tabs | View | Edit | Delete | Revisions | Clone | at the top.
I select | Edit |, which loads what I call an Edit Page.  On my display, this Edit Page has a box at the upper left with fields "Published", "Last Saved", and "Author" at the top.  Then there are several expandable blocks below it labeled "COMMENT SETTINGS", "META TAG", etc.
What is the name of that box?  The whole thing that includes the publication info and expandable blocks.
Thanks!

verticable tabs

You usually can find names by simply inspecting the HTML markup

Here you also can find some naming suggestions https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1838114

node form sidebar also a good candidate. Or node form details.

“Verticable”, should definitely be a word, but in the interests of making it a bit easier for the OP, it’s vertical tabs

Originally they are referred to as vertical tabs. Since screens got bigger and they moved to the sidebar they are nowadays also referred to as sidebar. See for example:

(D8) https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1838114
(D8) https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2916809
(D11) https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2893740

In code it's also referred to as advanced settings. See for example:

https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/10.2.7/core/modules/path/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/PathWidget.php?ref_type=tags#L53
https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/10.2.7/core/modules/comment/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/CommentWidget.php?ref_type=tags#L61


It's also referred to as "advanced settings" in the codebase, e.g. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21path%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldWidget%21PathWidget.php/function/PathWidget%3A%3AformElement/8.9.x and https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21comment%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldWidget%21CommentWidget.php/function/CommentWidget%3A%3AformElement/9

It sounds like "the advanced settings sidebar" is the clearest way to refer to this box, then.  Thanks to everyone!

Thanks @Clive – added to answer.
